# PHP :: handle typos in search

Tags: php, regex, search

I have a field to input your friend's name and search him up to add him as friend.
The problem is that if you are not sure how to spell his name like:
***Kris*** instead of **Chris** for example.
I think the right way to do this is use RegEx but I don't know how...

- How can I handle those kind of typos in PHP **?** 
  *(if it isn't possible in PHP then tell me how to do it in jQuery)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think a regex is not a good approach to check for typos and similar strings. I would consider something like levenshtein - PHP even has a native function for that, `levenshtein`.

EDIT: Depending on what you're looking for, there are other algorithms too that are also native in PHP: `soundex` (although considered superseded by newer approaches like Double Metaphone), `metaphone`, `similar_text`.

Comment: +1, although `metaphone`s are probably more to the point then levenshtein and others. They are _language specific_ though, if the current language isn't english another metaphone algorithm should be used.

Comment: Double Metaphone tries to include many other languages as well (there's an implementation available for PHP), although it's questionable how well it works in practice.

Answer (score 2):

Regex isn't appropriate for this. Your best bet is to create a set of names that group similar names with their spellings. So the name Chris would search for Kris, Chris, Kriss, etc.

A hash_map is probably a good choice. Levenshtein distance could sorta work, but you'll get a lot of false positives: (Camella vs Pamella for example).